# What is meant by the Fourier sine series?

Tags: fourier-series

The wording of the following problem confuses me:

> Find the Fourier sine series for $f(x)=x$, on $0\leq x<L$. To which value does the series converge at $x=\frac32 L$?

Can someone clarify what is meant by "the Fourier sine series"? From what I know, Fourier series are defined for functions with a domain $[-\pi, \pi]$. To get to this, we let
$$
\theta = \left(\frac{2x}{L}-1\right)\pi
$$
However, now the function $f(\theta)$ is not even in $\theta$ so the cosine terms won't dissapear.

Can someone clarify the situation for me?

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote?

Comment: It was probably in part due to the fact that you used an image when you could have just written the problem in LaTeX. You also had a few typos. I've fixed that for you.

Comment: The sine series is just the Fourier series without the cosine bits.

Comment: Extend the domain to $(-L,L)$ $x$ is anti-symmetric, so it's cosine coefficients are zero. $\theta=\frac{nx\pi}{2L}$

Comment: The "rationale" of a Fourier sine series is to take a "piece" of a function $f$ and replicate it in order to get another function $g$ which is 1) periodic 2) odd (with $g$ identical with $f$ on the concerned "piece"). For Fourier cosine series replace "odd" by "even".

Comment: @ryaron how is this not arbitrary? Can't I by this logic expand to $[-2L,2L]$ and get a different series?

Comment: Does it converge to the same function on $(0,L)$? If so and it is more tractable than yes.

Comment: Hi, I think it must converge to it by construction. Although I am not sure what tractable means. Does it mean for the smallest extension in domain? Also, do you know where I can find a source for this terminology?

Comment: Tractable means computable, if it is easier for me to compute a function by extension,  then i should extend.

Comment: How would you know how to extend it?